# Different behaviours in lookups fields

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lookup, search, lookup-field

I have a lightning component which has 4 lookup fields. 3 of them only suggest recently viewed records and the other suggest all records based on what are you typing.

The 4 fields are built in the same way. None of the objects/fields they point have lookup filters and the 4 objects are custom objects and they have their own tab.

Why is the difference in this behaviour?? I would like all fields suggest records based on what are you typing... I don't know if I'm missing something but I'm desperate.

Thanks in advance

Comment: **For your fourth, problem object, does the input suggest recently viewed if you view records of that object?** It sounds to me like some confusion about the behavior. The suggestions in the dropdown will not be records from across your org - if you need to actually search you will need to hit enter or click on the magnifying glass icon to search the entire org for records. The suggestion feature only goes so far and prefers records that you've viewed recently, so it is likely leveraging a cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior, as lookups suggest records from a cache and only perform a full search once you open up the search dialog (by hitting enter or clicking the "show all results for ___" suggestion). Once you do that, a search dialog will appear (this is customizable in how it searches and what columns it displays) and allow for an org-wide search. The mechanisms for how this works is the same as for SOSL or the search bar at the top of the org. [From the docs on Salesforce Search](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.search_lookupdialog.htm&type=5):

> **Search Behavior** When you perform a blank lookup, *a list of recently viewed records displays in the lookup search dialog*. For standard lookups, records are listed in alphabetical order by the primary record name field. For enhanced lookups, records are ordered according to when you last viewed them.

> Blank lookups for user records have slightly different behavior. If an admin selects **Use Recently Viewed User Records for Blank and Auto-Complete Lookups** on the Search Settings page, the user’s 200 most-recent records are returned and sorted in alphabetical order by first and last name. If this setting is not selected, the 200 most-recent records from across the org are returned and sorted in alphabetical order by first and last name.

[image: Suggestions]

[image: Search Dialog]